# Does the 7th of iiø7 in minor need to be prepared even used in a sequence?

Tags: voice-leading

I am writing a descending 5th sequence in minor and want to use a iiø7 (half diminished NOT diminished chord) instead of a ii° at the cadence. My textbook says in the chapter on supertonic 7th chord harmony that the 7th is usually prepared from the previous chord. Does this advice become null and void if the iiø7 is used in a sequence?

In a descending sequence of diatonic triads usually ^1 will come in the VI chord prior to the iiø7 chord but in past chapters before the sequences part "Harmony and voice leading" say the preparation of the 7th in supertonic chords must come in the same voice which might not be possible depending on the soprano one might choose. So my question is that since a sequence allows us to do all kinds of things otherwise discouraged or forbidden (like double leading tones and root position diminished triads) then shouldn't it be that such a strict preparation of the 7th in the iiø7 be unnecessary in the same voice as otherwise instructed in my book and we should see the sequence as overriding this requirement.

Comment: Does the sequence use sevenths in general? I'm not sure I get the book's point about preparing the seventh. Maybe there's a distinction between "usually" and "must."

Comment: Are you also using a 7th chord for the previous chord?

Comment: @Dekka no only the ii°7

Comment: Do you want to use ii°7 (fully diminished) or ii half-diminished 7? This is important because, assuming the previous chord is VI (e.g. an Ab chord in C minor) and has all chord tones in it, the 7th of ii half-diminished 7 has already been prepared, while the 7th of ii°7 has not. ii°7 does risk being confused with vii°7, though, so resolve ii°7 carefully.

Comment: Please edit to tell us about the whole sequence!

Comment: Is `ii°7` really the best description? In `C` that would be `D F Ab Cb`. Preparing that diminished seventh on an altered tonic seems tricky. What previous chord will have also been using a _chord tone_ of altered tonic? Enharmonically that chord is just a `viio7` chord.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Note, he's talking about minor. So, e.g., in A minor, B D F Ab. I still wanna know where it's coming from...

Comment: @AndyBonner, but the mode doesn't matter regarding a lowered tonic versus a leading tone. It's just as questionable in minor. I do agree, the actual sequence would be helpful to hear. There might be a misunderstanding.

Comment: Could you include a score showing what are you trying to do?

Comment: Echoing @user1079505's comment, I am not sure I understand the question.  By "descending 5th sequence" I presume you mean that the preceding chord is a VI chord.  Is this correct?  If so, is the problem that the third of the VI chord is a minor second above the seventh of the seventh of the ii°7 chord?

Comment: You say that "In a descending sequence of diatonic triads usually ^1 will come in the VI chord prior to the ii°7 chord" - you *do* really mean ii half-diminished 7 instead of ii°7, right?

Comment: yes correct, I have not yet got to fully diminished chords yet

Answer (score 1):

In real life you can do *whatever you want.*

The only time you can't do what you like is when emulating some well defined style or procedure, or taking a test. etc.

> My textbook says in the chapter on supertonic 7th chord harmony that the 7th is usually prepared from the previous chord.

The key word is "usually."

The textbook is giving you latitude. "Usually" the seventh is prepared. That means sometimes it is not prepared.

In such cases my attitude is this: write the passage several ways using various types of relative motion.

I think it's good to follow whatever the lessons asks, try alternatives, then examine the reason for using one or another treatment.

> Does this advice become null and void if the iiø7 is used in a sequence?

This seem worth addressing separately.

You're now moving beyond the specific lesson about preparing the seventh in the supertonic seventh chord. You should bring in other sources, like counterpoint or figured bass texts, to understand the principles involved and develop a broader view.

Historically, preparing suspensions comes out of *counterpoint*. So, IMO, it makes sense to understand the process in terms of *intervals* rather than Roman numeral chords. From that perspective the only question is whether the tone is dissonant with the bass. If it is, prepare the dissonance. Whatever the chord might be in Roman numeral analysis is irrelevant.

I think you can extend the same idea to dissonance preparation in sequences. I've never seen a source that makes a distinction between sequential or non-sequential passages. Again, the idea in strict counterpoint seems simply to prepare any dissonance in any type of passage.

Comment: What's the reason for the down vote?

Comment: "Do what you want" isn't an answer, and OP isn't asking the question of making aesthetic, which is what this post addresses. OP is trying to understand the history and reasoning behind the rules and guidelines laid out in Aldwell and Schachter.

Comment: And "do what you want" is obviously not my answer. I address both following the lesson of the textbook and an explanation, historically, why the suspension treatment does not depend on chord type.

Comment: "Do what you want" is your second sentence. If it's not your answer, then either remove it altogether (what I'd like to see), or at least move it to the end. And while you make vague references to history, your answer never directly addresses whether that history expects the preparation of the seventh in this scenario.

Comment: You don't tell me to remove stuff from my answers. You got your single down vote.

Comment: It's not an order — my apologies that it read that way — just a suggestion, along with an alternative.

Comment: @Aaron write your own answer that focuses on the _unnamed_ textbook. IMO the particular book doesn't matter. The textbook is just a point of departure. The OP's concern - IMO - is how to handle prepared dissonances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134377/discussion-between-aaron-and-michael-curtis).

Comment: The only thing that is relevant is if the tone is dissonant with the bass? A V in its inversions has many dissonances against the bass yet there is no mention of the need for preparing any of those in my textbook

Comment: @Armani. Yes, suspensions are in relation to the bass. Also, remember what I wrote about sticking to a textbook's lessons. You're jumping from a textbook lesson about preparing the seventh of `ii7` and trying to apply something of that particular point to sequential passages generally, or to the inversions of `V`, and then saying the textbook doesn't explain how to handle those other situations. If you stick with _only one textbook_, I think just stick to only it's lessons. If you want to expand on those lessons, you _must get other appropriate textbooks and compare them._

Comment: About preparing dissonances in the inversions of `V`. I assume you mean `V7`, because the only dissonant inversion of plain triad `V` is the P4 in `V6/4`. Keep in mind a prepared suspension is not the only way to account from the dissonances of `V7` and its inversions. Passing tones and neighbor motions are other ways to get the various dissonances.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant V7... V43 and V42 have dissonances against the bass which do not need to be prepared

Comment: Right. `I V4/3 I` would have the dissonant `^5` as a held tone while the other voiced moved as neighbor motions. `V V4/2 I6` would make held tones `^5 ^7` dissonant to the bass in a bass passing motion. I just mean that preparation/suspension isn't the only way to introduce dissonances with smooth voice leading.

Answer (score 1):

Preparation is melodically smooth.  Non-preparation is more melodically dramatic.  If you leap to a dissonant note, it will stand out.   Make sure that's what you want.

Comment: +1 for _positively_ stating what really guides the choice. It's about melodic line not chords.

Comment: Yes I understand that but sequences kind of overide things a bit as far as I can see so that might make leaping into the dissonance less of a problem

Comment: Do something once, it's wrong.  Do it twice, it's a sequence!